# Dictionary creation taking way longer on my coworkers computer

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, cprofile

My coworker asked me to look at his code and try to make it go faster. The goal of the code is to read some *large* excel sheets, do some operations with the data and then write to an excel sheet.

I realized the main problem in the code was the `pd.ExcelFile()` operation, on top of itself being a slow method it was being called a number of unnecessary times. Fixing this gave a **12x** speed up to the code.

Nevertheless, when running this on my coworkers computer the improvement is not there.
I've run a profile of the code (@ his PC) and found out that in his computer the most expensive operation is that of creating a dictionary for every sheet of the excel. Something like:

```
dts = {sheet_name: road_segment_file[i].parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in road_segment_file[i].sheet_names}
```

I'm using Ubuntu and running **Python 3.7.6** on the shell , while he's using windows and running **Python 3.8.5** with Spyder.

I have two questions then:

1. Any ideas on why the dictionary creation is way slower on his run?
2. How can in general a dictionary creation be sped up.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you both running the exact same code on the same computer?

Comment: same code, different computers with similar characteristics (i.e. same RAM)

Comment: How big approximately are the data chunks that you put in the dictionary? Also, what Python version is used in his Spyder and in your Ubuntu?

Comment: Disable antivirus?

Comment: The .xlsx are about 27 MB and each has 114 sheets so ~240KB/sheet